# WinRM HTTPS Connection to Windows 8 Systems

Tags: ssl, https, remote, windows-8, winrm

I have a couple virtual Windows 8 clients that I will be using to run some tests against a server.  I set up WinRM so I can easily pull the data back from all the clients for analysis but the data needs to be transferred through the HTTPS port.

I installed an SSL certificate on the Win8 client, created the listener with the below command, and opened port 5986 in the firewall.

```
winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{Hostname="CLIENT01";CertificateThumbprint="xxxx..."}
```

I can connect to the client without a problem through port 5985 but when I try to use SSL I get the error "Access is denied".  I've never had this problem using the SSL port on a Windows 2008 or Windows 2012 server so I'm thinking there must just be some other setting I need to change in Win8.  I've made sure my account is listed as an administrator on the client.  Anyone have an idea of what I might be missing?